# Checking if listbox contains table of signs

Tags: vba

I want to check value of text putted in listbox. If it contains one of this signs i should put error message. Is there any other way than checking it like that

```
If InStr(ListBox.list(i), ";") > 0 Or InStr(ListBox.list(i), "<") Or InStr(ListBox.list(i), ">")
```

Because i have to check about 30 signs so it will be pretty messy. Additional question, how can i check containing of `"` (quote), because if i put it like that `"""` it's not working.

Comment: For quote: You have to double a quote within a string, so you need to write `""""` - The first to start the string, the last to end the string and the 2 in the middle to tell the VBA runtime you want to have a quote within the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please. The quote makes part form the obtained array:

```
Sub testExistingSigns()
  Dim x As String, arrS As Variant, El As Variant, boolFound As Boolean
   arrS = Array(";", "<", ">", """", "|", ":")
    'or in this way:
   arrS = Split(";,<,>,"",|,:", ",") 'I prefer this one. It is shorter...
    'you will comment/delete the line which looks less convenient...
    'to test the first variant, please comment the second one.

   'test it:
   Debug.Print Join(arrS, " ")' Look in Immediate Window (Ctrl + G being in VBE)
   For Each El In arrS
        If InStr(ListBox.List(i), El) > 0 Then
            boolFound = True: Exit For
        End If
   Nex
   If boolFound Then Debug.Print "Ups..."
End Sub
```